# Change left-click behaviour to right-click and save-target-as. That is, make left-click to download file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have an mp4 video file on AWS S3 bucket. This AWS is my back-end.

On my Front-End, I have react app, where there is a `Download video` button (div) present. I can download the mp4 video file easily when I do right-click and 'Save-Link-As ...'. But I want this behavior to happen on simple left-click. I want the download to start simply on left-clicking.
In below code - `item.vidUrl` contains the URL of video. The URL is correct.

```
              <a
                // display="inline-block"
                href={item.vidUrl}
                download
                // target="_blank"
                // rel="noreferrer"
              >
                <div>
                  <p style={{ color: 'white' }}>Download video</p>
                </div>
              </a>
```

When left-clicking the `Download video` button, the above code opens the video and starts playing it in the current browser window. I dont want this behaviour. I want that when a user left-clicks, a dialog box to open asking where to download the video on local computer.

Comment: Set the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header on S3 objects that you want to be treated as an attachment.